# inline svg sprite white space issue

Tags: svg

In Chrome and Firefox (haven't tested elsewhere yet), I am seeing a large chunk of white space above and below my svg.

I am using an inline svg sprite sheet (built with gulp svgstore) and referencing the svg by symbol id

**html**

```
<svg style="display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol id="test" viewBox="0 0 111.2 33"><g></g><g>  <rect x="0" y="0" fill="#843B8F" width="111.2" height="33"/></g></symbol></svg>

<svg class="sym">
   <use xlink:href="#test"></use>
</svg>
```

Here is an example:

http://codepen.io/magicspon/pen/dPVKZm

How can I remove this white space?

Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your viewBox aspect ratio doesn't correspond to the shape its displayed in. The shape it's displayed in is 300 x 150 as you haven't supplied any dimensions to that `<svg>` object (the one with the class="sym" attribute).

So you could either

- give that `<svg>` element width and height with the aspect ratio 111.2:33 or
- add a preserveAspectRatio="none" attribute to the `<symbol>` element

depending on what you want to display

Comment: preserveAspectRatio="none"  seems to have done the job, haven't tested it fully, but t'is looking good... many thanks